# New OSL Closures

Tags: scripting, osl

There’s an interesting thing about updating OSL closures in blender.
As principled hair **BSDF** was released a new function `principled_hair()` [appeared](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/osl.html#hair) but I can’t see any updates to **BSSRDF** functions. (random walk ?)
So, is there any way to implement it independently?
Or it’s worth to wait utill devs would include it?

Comment: This is the commit that added random walk, it appears to have been added to OSL at the time? https://developer.blender.org/rB0df9b2c#change-EuTsoMgg1KjS